# Why the <ul> class "list-inline" <li> on mobile is not at the same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list

i am adding "team items" into ul with a class "list-inline".

Now my full width will give me 6 columns in the ul.

In some width, the numbers of the columns is started to be 5 then 4...1 (you know, it's responsive).

**Now from 2 to 5 columns it makes problems like the zikzak and it is not in the same line.**
(see photo)

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="list-inline team_list">
                    <li class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12"><img src="images/team/16.jpg" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 team_list_title_div">
                                <div class="col-md-12 team_list_title_bold_div">Sharon Steinbaum</div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 team_list_title_regular_div">External Relations and Resource Development</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12"><img src="images/team/12.jpg" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 team_list_title_div">
                                <div class="col-md-12 team_list_title_bold_div">Avital Sincai</div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 team_list_title_regular_div">Partner Skr law<br>Founder of Spark</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12"><img src="images/team/13.jpg" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 team_list_title_div">
                                <div class="col-md-12 team_list_title_bold_div">Ofer Burstein</div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 team_list_title_regular_div">Ceo Koren Industrial Park <br>Founder of Spark</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

and here is my css:

```
    .team_list {
float:none;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
max-width:980px;
}
.team_list li {
background:white;
width:100%;
max-width:128px;
padding:0;
float:none;
margin:0 10px 10px 10px;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
font-family:tahoma;
}
.team_list img {
display:inline-block;
}
.team_list li:hover {
transform: scale(1.1);
}
.team_list_title{
   text-align:center;
   min-height:50px;
   display:table;
   width:100%;
}
.team_list_title span {
   border: 1px solid #0ca1ce;
   background:white;
   padding:10px;
   font-size:17px;
   border-radius:20px;
}
.team_list_title_div {
color:#2e2e2e;
}
.team_list_title_bold_div {
font-size:10px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.team_list_title_regular_div {
font-size:10px;
min-height:45px;
}
```

and this is a picture of my problem:
[image]

any help please ?

Comment: use vertical-align: top;

Comment: @Krish i tryed on the li ... didnt worked :\

Comment: please share a working fiddle demo!

Comment: Adding a vertical align top should do the trick. Here is a working fiddle of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/wg8ujg28/

Comment: i just copied and pasted your code, and not worked :\

Comment: thank you @Krish , it's worked ! i just updated the wrong file ! thanks bro :)

Comment: ok, I have added that as answer, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `vertical-align: top;` to `li`.

```
.team_list li {
      background:white;
      width:100%;
      max-width:128px;
      padding:0;
      float:none;
      margin:0 10px 10px 10px;
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      font-family:tahoma;
      vertical-align: top; /*new line*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align: top;` to `.team_list li` will solve your issue.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5zpky76/)**